# Scheduled Cronjob to run a C program, but a piece of that program is not running

Tags: c++, cron

The program is called temper, built from temper.c and some header files.

It's purpose is to turn something on or off depending on the temperature that I get from a usb thermometer.

(skipping the boring parts)vi temper.c:

```
if (tempc > 61)
{ 
    system("br a1 on"); 
    printf("The temperature was above 61 degrees");
}
else if(tempc < 60){ system("br a1 off"); }
```

crontab -e:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/username/endpath; ./temper >> tempLog.txt
```

tempLog.txt says: "The temperature was above 61 degrees" on every line, at every minute. So I know that it's entering that statement, but it's not performing the system command.

I'm at a loss.

Edit: 'br a1 on' is a command for x10 home automation using 'BottleRocket'.

Comment: Check the return value from the `system` call. If negative there was an error, and you can check `errno` to see what it was.

Comment: 99.9% of cron issues are environment issues. 78% of those issues are `PATH` issues. Where is `br`? Is it in the extremely restricted `PATH` that cron sets up for your job?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Impressive figures. I like your grasp of statistcs.

Comment: You should replace the "br a1 on" by something like "echo" or "ls" that is definitely in your path. Make sure there are no environment issues like Charles says.

Comment: It's like Charles and pitseeker said. Check your path: printf(getenv("PATH")). Just for these types of reasons I find that wrapping these kinds of things in shell scripts is the way to go.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @CharlesBailey, you should give the full path to the br command and not rely on it beeing on your path. You can find out about the complete path by entering `which br` in a terminal.